# Javascript Changing Class' Style

Tags: javascript, css

I want to change the background color of a class named "Zones" to blue and i've tried:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("Zones").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
```

But it's for some reason not working...

Comment: Is there more than 1 class? or just the one?

Comment: Because `getElementsByClassName` returns HTMLCollection.... You have to loop through each element... and apply style

Answer (score 3):

If there is only one class, you can do this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("Zones")[0].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
```

If there is more than 1 class, you can do this:

```
var zonesLength = document.getElementsByClassName.length;

for(i = 0; zonesLength < i; i++) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("Zones")[i].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but just out of curiosity, what do i do when there are more?

Comment: Sorry, i just realised you already said that.

Comment: No worries. Glad I could help @user9363416